# How to make a textView in android to be clickable or act like hyperlink

Tags: android

I want to a make a textView text like "**Meanwhile check the similar products**" to be act like clickable link or url.(i.e) when someone clicks on the text it will hit an Api to fetch the data and shows a new activity.

Comment: on `TextView` set `OnClickListener` and do whatever you want ..

Comment: Try @Abhishek Patel answer and on click hit api....Run async .....

Comment: You can use `Html.fromhtml()` or use `SpannableString`

Answer (score 2):

Try This it may be help to you

```
tvLink.setText( Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"your url\">Meanwhile check the similar products</a>"));
tvLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Added a missing "\"

Answer (score 1):

To make the TextView automatically identify and make the URLs clickable, you just have to put

> android:autoLink="web"

property in your TextView's xml.

Answer (score 1):

Please use like this code

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:text="@string/your_text" />
```

**in java file**

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v){

//put Your API To call

}

});
```

Comment: This is easiest. Just put autoLink="all" in your TextView xml.

Comment: Depends on how you do it I guess .. in my app I have an "about" dialog with strings I define in strings.xml and all I have to do is put in the autoLink and all web addresses and email addresses in that string get an auto-link

Comment: For example adding the autoLink="all" into a TextView that text is "Visit my website at www.mywebsite.com and email me at myemail@domain.com" -- then that website and that email will automatically become clickable links.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

and you can also use

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying many cases but always fails. But **finally** found the **solution**.

If you want TextView with links clickable as below:
[image]

You need format your TextView like that:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/textViewPrivacy"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/signUpPrivacyText"
    android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

Note, that `android:linksClickable="true"` is important!

String resource must be like this:

```
<string name="signUpPrivacyText">By continuing you are indicating that you agree with <a href="http://example.com">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="http://example.com">Privacy Policy</a></string>
```

Then, you need this in your code:

```
TextView tvPrivacy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrivacy);
tvPrivacy.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

That's all! Happy codding!